# What is the iPad's screen refresh rate?

Tags: ipad

Is it 60 Hz like the phones/touches?

Comment: I've seen the number 60Hz floating around the net for the iPad, but can't find any super trustworthy sources the explicitly state this number. I'd say it's a safe bet though.

Comment: 60 Hz is good enough for geometry dash lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

60Hz.

Apple DTS has not changed any of their answers about 60Hz refresh rates with respect to any device model, and no one has reported any higher rate.

Update: In 2017, Apple introduced new iPad Pro devices capable of higher display refresh rates than 60 Hz.

Answer (score 4):

Apple [introduced](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2017/06/ipad-pro-10-5-and-12-9-inch-models-introduces-worlds-most-advanced-display-breakthrough-performance/) 2nd generation of iPad Pro models in June 2017 which feature ProMotion display technology, which delivers refresh rates of upto 120Hz. ProMotion also improves display quality and reduces power consumption by automatically adjusting the display refresh rate to match the movement of the content.

It comes in two variants with 10.5" and 12.9" screen sizes.