# Screen refresh rates on mobile devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod-touch, screen, refresh

Are there any hand held devices, PDA , phones or pads that have a screen refresh rate of 120Hz.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8006/what-is-the-ipads-screen-refresh-rate

Comment: Just wondering... Why would you want that?

Comment: @Cawas - The only thing I can think of is mobile active-shutter 3d stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with devices that have LCD screens (and not CRTs), it ultimately doesn't matter what the refresh rate is -- what matters most is how quickly a pixel can change from one color to another, and this isn't constant across the color range the device can display.

It is important how certain videos are processed since 24p can't fit into 60 equally (hence the supposed value of 120hz), but you'll find conflicting views as to if it is all that noticeable, useful, and/or even desirable. Let's just say this: I've never had a problem watching a video on my iPhone or iPad and noticing bad motion blur or odd artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

120 Hz is exactly 2x refresh rate for room lighting in the USA. You sure you won't set up unwanted interference? It may be subtle, but it might become tiring.

I'm not sure refresh rate is that important with modern non-CRT displays. The difference between min and max lumens is significantly lower these days than with the old technology, isn't it?

Comment: Odds are the OP wants that sync with US power in order to videotape them without having scan lines show. Since these aren't CRTs, though, it shouldn't be a problem. I know that I've videorecorded iPhone and iPad screens with no problems whatsoever.